# How to collapse a WinForm Panel with controls docked to top inside of it

Tags: vb.net, winforms, width, panel, dock

I have a WinForm Panel (a SideMenu basically) with some controls docked to top inside of it. I want these controls don't collapse when the panel collapses to the left. I saw that if I undock the controls then the panel will collapse properly. But I need the controls docked to top of the container Panel. How can I do to achieve this?

```
Private Sub btnMenu_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMenu.Click
    If Me.SideMenu.Width = 60 Then
        Me.SideMenu.Width = 225
        'Do something
        '
        '
        'Finish
    Else 'If panel is in the original size... (Width = 225)
        Me.SideMenu.Width = 60
        'Do something
        '
        '
        'Finish
End Sub
```

EDIT1:

This is the SideMenu:

[image: SideMenu expanded]

This is what I want:

[image: SideMenu collapsed]

This is what I have:

[image: SideMenu incorrectly collapsed]

Comment: You may want to include a before and after collapse picture to show what is happening and describe how it differs from what you want to happen.

Comment: One option would be to put another `Panel` inside that `Panel`. You can make the inner `Panel` the same as the maximum size of the outer `Panel` and then dock the other controls in the inner `Panel`. When you collapse the outer `Panel`, the inner `Panel` will remain the same size and the child controls will be unaffected.

Comment: Using plain panels is probably a bit nasty for this when there are other panels that are intended to move or collapse but I agree with the picture comment- it's hard to visualize your needs from what you have described. Screenshots of what you have and what you want, please!

Comment: Is there any reason why in your collapse/expand code you can just control the docking of the controls in the panel? Iterate SideMenu.Controls() and set the dock to Top/None as required.  Might also need to keep track of the Z-Order maybe

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable comments. I added some pictures in order to show what I'm looking for.